# How can generate jar of volley framework?

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying generate jar of volley framework. Following the documentation have this example: `android update project -p` and `ant jar`.
I tried execute this commands but return `command not found`

I'm using Windows 7, my SDK_HOME is in c:\SDK

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The volley project converted their build process to gradle.  Here are the steps I used to build volley as an aar on OS X.  (Assuming you already have git, gradle, and android dev tools setup and working)

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/.android-sdk/android-sdk-macosx
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
cd volley
```

Configured roblectric and its dependencies

```
echo 'emulateSdk=18'>>src/test/resources/org.robolectric.Config.properties
cat<<END>rules.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
}
END
```

Build the aar

```
gradle wrapper
./gradlew clean build
```

Output files will be located under

```
build/outputs/aar
```

Finally to include the resulting aar files in your Android project; copy the volley-release.aar file to the libs subdirectory under your project and add the following to your projects build.gradle file

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

compile('com.android.volley:volley-release:1.0.0@aar')
```